# google analytics referral url doesn't have related link to my site

Tags: google-analytics

When i check my google analytics referral urls find something interesting,

i have a link in a site domain but only some specific pages which mean the referral urls should only display these specific page urls , however , The pages listed  as referring pages on the  site don’t contain direct links to my site. I open one of the page and didn't the link linked to my site. Anyone knows what happened or why display so many unrelated links~ any solution?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Do they perhaps contain links to something else that has the same Google Analytics identifier as the pages you are interested in? I am pretty sure that's what it goes by, not your domain. Just a thought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted this answer to another question just a few minutes ago. But the answer suits this question too.

I believe you are a victim of GA spam.
This is because the UA code is visible in the html, and anyone can find it and use it to create referral traffic.
The idea is that you as the admin is looking at the statistics and wonder what that referral page is and clicks on it.
It may be harmless or can be flooded with spam popups or even viruses.

To make sure you don't get this you need to verify that the statistics that is shown on GA is coming from *real users* on **your page**.
You can do that by adding a dimension to your GA send code that you in GA admin use to filter on.

Example:

```
ga('send', 'pageview', {
      'dimension1':  'Y'
 });
```

Here I add dimension1 to the send code with the value Y.
This means if a user is on your page and use your GA JavaScript code it will always send dimension1 as value 'Y'.
If you add this and let it stay on for a day or two, just to make GA collect some data of it.

Then go in GA admin section and choose filter.
Now you want to **exclude** all traffic that does not have dimension1 as value 'Y'.

This means any spam traffic is not picked up in your report.
Only if someone actually looks at your GA code will they be able to put spam in your statistics, but usually the spam is generated by software that is (yet) not smart enough to do that.

Comment: thanks ~ really helpful ~ another question is my page only have the GTM code there ~ if i want to set up the verify code as what you show above , where to put them ?

Comment: @user1234 I can't even find anything about GTM code. You need to link somewhere so that I can see what that is.

Comment: Is it this type of code? https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/custom-dims-mets

Comment: yep~ pretty much the type of code you post there @Andreas

Comment: @user1234 In that case I think you can just follow those instructions there on how to add the custom dimension. And then add the filter as I explained in my code.

Comment: @user1234 Not sure if you have to add it maunually or it just does it automatically but there is a section in the admin section called Custom Definitions -> Custom Dimensions. When I look there in my account I see my custom dimensions. Maybe you need to at them there first.

Comment: really appreciate your reply i added it as you said ~ will see how is going through ! Thanks again ~